# Compiling explicit double array definitions as binary resource in a DLL - is there a better way?

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, binary, compiler-optimization

I am currently using some explicit array definition like the following in my code:

```c
double * p = new double[5]{
      0.029426,   0.029366,   0.029281,   0.029157,   0.028979
};
```

but with much bigger array-sizes. The reason I do this is, because I get the data in this ASCII text-form and want to be able to add it directly as binary data to the created DLL. Swapping the text before compiling is automated, but I want to avoid additional pre-compilation steps.

Now I've noticed two things:

a) compiling this code becomes really slow for larger arrays

b) the resulting DLL is much bigger than the array's binary data size should be

c) If I change `double` to `float` this does not really change the DLL size

All of this makes me wonder if there is not a (much) better way to do it, but so far I haven't found an answer here on SO which helped me, although I've seen a couple of related questions.

**Can somebody explain why I see b) and c)?**

**Can somebody suggest a better method that takes (float/double) data as ASCII and embeds it as binary in a DLL but doesn't require pre-compilation steps?**

Other hints or suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Why the `new`? It makes me guess that this makes a duplicate at run-time: the constant array which has to be stored somewhere and the appearance on heap after the construction. (It's not the direct answer to your questions but it might be related.)

Comment: Regarding c) : Did you change it to `float * p = new float[5] { 0.029426, ...` or to `0.029426f`? Without the `f` the binary data are still `double`s.

Comment: `double * p = new double[5]{...}` -> `double p[] {...}`

Comment: @mch Without the F it didn't even compile for me. But thanks for the hint. Yes, I did.

Comment: @Jabberwocky trying right now... Will comment once done.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It helped *somewhat*, but not to the extend I was hoping. Original binary data of all arrays is about 3 MB. My code increased the DLL size by 10.6 MB, your suggestion increases the DLL by 7.5 MB (so still more than double of the binary size)

Answer (score 2):

Checking the assembler output, it seems like using `new` have a significant overhead.

Using your example we get assembly like.

```cpp
double * p = new double[5]{
      0.029426,   0.029366,   0.029281,   0.029157,   0.028979
};
```

[yields](https://godbolt.org/z/116d5ncYW)

```
p:
        .zero   8
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jne     .L3
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 65535
        jne     .L3
        mov     edi, 40
        call    operator new[](unsigned long)
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     rax, rdx
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 8
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 8
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 8
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 8
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC4[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     QWORD PTR p[rip], rdx
.L3:
        nop
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_p:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1855700750
        .long   1067327961
.LC1:
        .long   -428534657
        .long   1067323934
.LC2:
        .long   -1517051168
        .long   1067318230
.LC3:
        .long   634143331
        .long   1067309909
.LC4:
        .long   -988460953
        .long   1067297963
```

However, when not using `new` the compiler can just save everything as raw data:

```cpp
const double p[] = {
      0.029426,   0.029366,   0.029281,   0.029157,   0.028979
};
```

yields [something like](https://godbolt.org/z/PoEx65T3r)

```
        .file   "example.cpp"
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .text
.Ltext0:
        .section        .rodata
        .align 32
        .type   p, @object
        .size   p, 40
p:
        .long   1855700750
        .long   1067327961
        .long   -428534657
        .long   1067323934
        .long   -1517051168
        .long   1067318230
        .long   634143331
        .long   1067309909
        .long   -988460953
        .long   1067297963
        .text
```

Edit: (Lift in commend that seem to be a solution)
If you put it in a header file, it is possible that the data ends upp multiple times in the library, and in that case, putting it in the cpp-files could help, and then you would need to use a function or extern variable to access it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it in the assembler code. I did make the change for testing, but it only gave me about 25% of DLL size reduction, using about 7.5MB to store about 3MB of data.

Comment: @BmyGuest Just a thought: If compile-times is not that much of a problem, have you conosidered taking some header only zip-library, converting it to constexprp and store everything in a constexpr variable? Maybe  a lot of work, but if you really do not want to have a extra pre-compile-step it could be a possible way to go.

Comment: @BmyGuest Another thought. I just wanted to double-check where you put the data variable. If you put it in a header file, it is possible that the data ends upp multiple times in the library, and in that case, putting it in the cpp-files could help, and then you would need to use a function or extern variable to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. To code is in an include (just wrapping a function call around the text-endcoded array) included from a .cpp. I think I was just surprised that things bloat up so much.

Comment: Ok nice. Added that to the answer:)

Comment: The two code snippets you show are identical.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ops. Copy paste error. Fixed now

Comment: The first code will probably be very different if the initialisation array is larger.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, ok please provide example